# Create a comment box as in Excel inside angular grid

Tags: angular, angular-grid

I am working on an angular grid where on hovering in an cell user should be able to add or update a note or a 'Comment' just like we have in Excel (a small test area should popup next to the cell with some text and should be editable).

can anyone suggest way to accomplish this requirement.